# Issue with php "while" statement using $i

Tags: php, while-loop

Really stumped on this, my code keeps falling over on the below section. I really can't see why, any clues at all would be really very much appreciated!

```
    $message = "Order Number : ".$order_number."\n";
    $message .= "Coupon : ".$coupon."\n"."\n";
    $i = 0;
while (++$i) {
  if (isset($_POST['course'.$i.''])) {
    # we have a course defined, lets add it to the message.
    $message .= "Race ".$i."      : ".$_POST['course'.$i.'']."\n";
    $message .= "Date        : ".$_POST['day'.$i.'']."\n";
    $message .= "Time        : ".$_POST['hr'.$i.''].":".$_POST['min'.$i.'']."\n";
    $message .= "Race Number : ".$_POST['numb'.$i.'']."\n";
    $message .= "Race Name   : ".$_POST['name'.$i.'']."\n";
    $message .= "Horse       : ".$_POST['horse'.$i.'']."\n"."\n";

  } else {   
   break;
  }
}  
    $message .= "Copies      : ".$_POST['copies']."\n";
    $message .= "Phone       : ".$_POST['custphone']."\n";
    $message .= "Total Cost  : ".$order_amount."\n";
```

var_dump $message:

```
    Order Number : 50638785
    Coupon : 

    Copies      : 1
    Phone       : 0123456789
    Total Cost  : 80.00
```

var_dump $post:

array(13) { ["course1"]=> string(4) "BRIG" ["day1"]=> string(10) "16-07-2014" ["hr1"]=> string(2) "15" ["min1"]=> string(2) "30" ["numb1"]=> string(2) "06" ["name1"]=> string(14) "Grand National" ["horse1"]=> string(9) "Buttercup" ["custphone"]=> string(11) "01234567898" ["coupon"]=> string(0) "" ["country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["copies"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> string(5) "80.00" ["B1"]=> string(3) "Buy" }

Comment: You should replace ++$i with condition. Move increment to the loop body.

Comment: Why not `while (isSet($_POST[..$i])) { ... $i++; }`?

Comment: What errors do you get? What is not working? The code is valid and runs for me.

Comment: When I run var_dump for $_POST I get all the data in the code but when I run var_dump on $message it excludes everything within this "while"

Comment: First time you refer to $_POST array your `$i=1`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Yes the first value is course1 then the clones are course2, course3 etc..

Comment: Can you paste var_dump of an example `$_POST` and `$message` that it produces?

Comment: I edited the original post to include var_dumps and other values added to £message

Comment: I executed this code with given values and everything worked out perfectly. The problem must be somewhere else.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e8215968e1bdf4fc815e00ae6bf16a81f9e4ecf

Comment: Merlins Beard! You are absolutely right. I will soldier on elsewhere in that case. Thanks very much for your help, been reading Stack Overflow for years and this is the first time I have had to post/get involved, very impressed with everyone's response! Hopefully now I have an account I can answer someone else's day too. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

This may be nicer:

```
 $i = 0 ;    
 while(isset($_POST['course'.$i.''])) {
        # we have a course defined, lets add it to the message.
        $message .= "Race ".$i."      : ".$_POST['course'.$i.'']."\n";
        $message .= "Date        : ".$_POST['day'.$i.'']."\n";
        $message .= "Time        : ".$_POST['hr'.$i.''].":".$_POST['min'.$i.'']."\n";
        $message .= "Race Number : ".$_POST['numb'.$i.'']."\n";
        $message .= "Race Name   : ".$_POST['name'.$i.'']."\n";
        $message .= "Horse       : ".$_POST['horse'.$i.'']."\n"."\n";
        $i++;
 }
```

Comment: You should pre-increment `$i` rather than post-increment it, otherwise the message will contain content for the wrong course.